# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\log(n)}{(n!)}$ Convergent using comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried comparison test using $1/n!$ as the test series but when I use it in ratio, I get $\log(n)$ which goes to infinity which means the test series is divergent which is not true so I cannot figure out which series I can pick out that can be used in the comparison test.

Comment: No, it does not follow that the series is divergent. Read the comparison test again - read the fine print this time...

Comment: Yes if you suppose take an a series (which you want ti check if convergent or not) and another test series bn and take the ratio an/bn and IF this ratio gives finite value then both the series an and bn converge or diverge together correct?

Comment: If the **limit of** the ratio is **strictly positive** and finite then the two series converge or diverge together. That's the LIMIT OF the ratio! Here the limit of the ratio is infinite, so the test says nothing.

Comment: Ohhhhh Ok Ok, thanks for clearing that out !

Comment: Glad to help. **Hint** for if you want to be better at this math stuff: Review what happened here. I told you that you had the test wrong, you should read it again, very carefully. And after I said that you still came back with an incorrect version of the test! Really, all you need to do is read much more carefully - I cleared things up for you by doing nothing more than stating the test exactly as it appeared in front of you when you looked it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $\ln\left(n\right)<n$ for $n$ positive real number,then:

$$\sum_{n\ge1}^{ }\frac{\ln\left(n\right)}{n!}<\sum_{n\ge1}^{ }\frac{n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge0}^{ }\frac{1}{n!}=e$$

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative since eventually

$$n!\ge n^3\ge n^2\ln n$$

$$\sum_{n\ge n_0}^{ }\frac{\ln\left(n\right)}{n!}\le\sum_{n\ge n_0}^{ }\frac{\ln n}{n^2\ln n}=\sum_{n\ge n_0}^{ }\frac{1}{n^2}$$

which converges.

Comment: But n^2(logn) > n right? for n greater than 2?

Comment: @RiRi In the first way we have bounded $\ln n$ from above, here we have bounded $n!$ from below to ontain a different way for the comparison test.

Comment: Of course $n^2(\log n) > n $ but it is not essential for that answer.

Comment: I made a mistake you're right because even if you take the inverse of n^2(logn) > n it doesn't change the inequality you have given above, the series at question is still finite and only proves your answer further.